# Crash when user tap "Reset" in new iOS DateTimePicker

Tags: html, ios, swift, ios14

I open our HTML in `WebView` with a date field, but on `iOS 14` when a user tap button `reset` I catch the crash

```
Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=2, address=0x36b90b7b50)

#0  0x00000001be6a60f8 in objc_msgSend ()
#1  0x00000001b680073c in -[WKDateTimePicker setDateTimePickerToInitialValue] ()
#2  0x00000001b6800134 in -[WKDateTimePicker reset:] ()
```

I think it is `Apple Crash`, but how I can workaround this case? Maybe there is a way how to fix `HTML`, or do something on `iOS` side [screen example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ozJun.jpg)

[one more link](https://www.mail-archive.com/webkit-changes@lists.webkit.org/msg163824.html)

Comment: What's the crash message? Did you set exception breakpoints in Xcode?

Comment: Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=2, address=0x36b90b7b50)

Comment: some like this https://www.mail-archive.com/webkit-changes@lists.webkit.org/msg163824.html

Comment: According to the log Crash occurs due to the use of an autoreleased NSString in
    setDateTimePickerToInitialValue. To fix, make the variable
    a RetainPtr.

Comment: Again, where does your app stop with exception breakpoints?

Comment: Is there a solution to this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this issue with `swizzling` methods

```
let originalSelector = #selector(app.sendAction(_:to:from:for:))
let swizzledSelector = #selector(app.log_sendAction(_:to:from:for:))
```

and in `log_sendAction` i checking

- **if** `iOS Version` .available(14..<15)
- **and if** `action: Selector` .contains(find: "reset:")
- **and if** `to target: Any?` .contains(find: "WKDateTimePicker")
- **then** skeep call original `originalSelector`